# Getting document structure of parent

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to obtain the document structure for the main browser display in javascript in order to change text spans from within a window opened in a manner supported by most browsers.

I have tried below and it works if I debug through visual studio using ie10 (not if I run it straight in the browser), chrome either non/debug however not in firefox whether I debug or not. when it is not working document throws up as undefined.

```
moWindow.parentElement.document.getElementById("status_txt").textContent = "Translate(Saving_view)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.top.document.getElementById("status_txt").innerHTML = "Translate(Saving_view)";
```